# App registered in v2 endpoints, why is 'user and group' option disappeared?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I registered an app in v2 endpoint (apps.dev.microsoft.com), however in azure portal, I cannot see the 'user and group' option where I would like to control the access by security groups, is this feature supported??
[image]

Comment: Are you signed in with an admin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because that the App you created is a **Native App**.

I did a test and found that  when you registered a Native App and granted permissions to it. It would occurs in Enterprise Applications without Users and Groups . Just like this:

[image]

> Native client registrations are multi-tenant by default. You don’t
>   need to take any action to make a native client application
>   registration multi-tenant.

If you want to have the Users and Groups section, you need to register **Web app/API**  application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, @TOMMY WANG . If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer to help more communities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported - Applications created in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) (v2) will show up in [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com) under Enterprise Apps and you should be able to assign permissions to it.

It is likely that you are not seeing this because you are not signed in as *Tenant Admin*.

Comment: Thanks could you please take a look at this further q? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/80884410?noredirect=1